# Fedora, Kernel 4.6.7 and nVidia Optimus or Prime

Tags: fedora, nvidia, nouveau, optimus

**What I try to achieve**

Using both my Intel chipset and my GeForce 940M.

**My configuration**

Laptop model : Asus Zenbook UX303UB

```
$ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)

$ lsmod | grep nouveau
nouveau              1511424  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    90112  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        143360  2 i915,nouveau
drm                   339968  13 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi

$ uname -a
Linux user 4.6.7-300.fc24.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 17 18:48:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**I followed the following guides**

- http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/ (didn't work because this solution is for laptop with only one card. so I was stucked with a black screen when I tried to reboot)
- http://negativo17.org/complex-setup-with-nvidia-optimus-nouveau-prime-on-fedora-20/ (not detailed enough for my Linux level, the "install nvidia driver normally" is a little bit too broad :) so when I tried it, I wasn't able to boot to graphical UI anymore)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME (but `xrandr --listproviders` only gives me one provider, the intel one)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee (it works :D but I have to use optirun everytime :-( )

**What I would like**

1. Simple usage of desktop application, using nVidia GPU if needed (i.e. automatic offloading)
2. Shutdown nVidia card to enhance battery life
3. Bumblebee seems to be a good option as I have to manually launch applications with `optirun`

I will provide any needed information :-D Just ask in the comments. I have a limited knowledge about Linux (only basics stuff) and nearly null knowledge about graphical stuff (X, rendering process, etc...).

Comment: This is no help to you now, but I know the graphics team is working on making this work better for Fedora 25 and beyond. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Workstation/Tasklist#Fedora_Workstation_25

Comment: thank you very much for this information anyway :D could give help if needed ? (like, info/log/anything else)

Comment: Let me check...

Answer (score 2):

I know Arch is the pinnacle of Linux distro documentation, but in this case there is also an [Excellent guide to Bumblebee on Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee).

Unfortunately, I'm afraid this will get you to the same place: *"it works :D but I have to use optirun everytime :-("*, which, by your sad-face, is not what you want.

The good news is that better Optimus support is in the works for Fedora 25 and beyond (see [Fedora Workstation — Tasklist](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Workstation/Tasklist#Fedora_Workstation_25)), although I know that doesn't immediately help you.